# If I add url "http://www.yahoo.com" in iframe, it is giving error "Refused to display, set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' ". so how to solve?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a iframe in page , and whatever url I type to address bar, it renders that url in the iframe, but for http://www.yahoo.com , it is showing blank iframe and giving me error "Refused to display 'https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'"

Now i want to handle this error, May be i can redirect user to directly to www.yahoo.com...

Please Give me Some Solution.How Can i solve it?

THANKS

Comment: This is to prevent malicious pages from appearing like legitimate ones. It's not meant to be bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; Yahoo has used the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header to "opt out" of having their site displayed in a frame. This header cannot be overridden by your page.

Pick another site to put in your iframe.

Comment: is not even possible with proxy or something?